# parsing date object with jodatime not working

Tags: android, datetime, jodatime

When I try to parse Date object which has a format like `1950-01-01T00:00:00` then date time get it as yesterday.

i also tried to get time zone with `DateTimeZone.getDefault()` but its still not working.
Which timezone can I use to fix it?

`DateTime dateTime = new DateTime(1950-01-01T00:00:00, DateTimeZone.UTC);`

```
output:
dateTime.getDayOfMonth() = 31
dateTime.getMonthOfYear() = 12
dateTime.getYear() = 1949
```

Can you please help me?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

fixed with adding below code in application class

> DateTimeZone.setDefault(DateTimeZone.forID("Europe/Istanbul"));

Comment: `DateTime dateTime = new DateTime(1950-01-01T00:00:00, DateTimeZone.forID("Europe/Istanbul"));` would be better in order to avoid manipulating the default time zone (maybe the user on the mobile phone wants another one per standard, or other apps or other parts of the app shall not suffer from such a change).

Comment: @Meno thats local app :)